# SQL Find Most Frequent Route

Tags: sql

| Departure | Destination | FlightCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 5 |
| B | A | 4 |
| A | C | 7 |
| C | A | 1 |

I need to find the most frequent flight regardless of the flight directions from the above table.

For example, instead of A-C route having the most flight count of 7, I want the result to show A-B/B-A which have total flight count of 9.

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Include a code sample and describe how it doesn't fit your needs. Also tag the question with the specific database platform you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can standardize the order of departure and destination by ordering them lexicographically using `least` and `greatest`:

```sql
WITH standardized AS (
    SELECT least(departure, destination) location1,
           greatest(departure, destination) location2
      FROM flight
)
SELECT location1,
       location2, 
       count(*) FlightCount
  FROM standardized
 GROUP BY location1, location2
```

Output:

| location1 | location2 | FlightCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 9 |
| A | C | 8 |

Comment: Thank you, would it be possible to do this without using Least or Greatest fuctions?

Comment: Yes, you could replace the functions with `CASE` statements such as this one for location1: `CASE WHEN departure < destination THEN departure ELSE destination END location1`.